# How can I carry a php session number past a javascript page?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a page that relies on php sessions to carry a variable called $audit_id.

The page that uses it then uses a javascript page to carry out a function at which on the successful redirects the page to a new page, at this point it loses the session value.

Is there a way that I can carry the variable past the javascript page?

Hopefully, to clarify what I mean, this is the basic structure...

**upload_image.php:**

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['audit_id'];
$audit_id = $_SESSION['audit_id'];
```

**script.js**

```
$('#loading-content').html('Uploading Complete!');
window.location = "http://www.dentaldigs.co.uk/upload_success.php";
```

**upload_success.php:**

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['audit_id'];
$audit_id = $_SESSION['audit_id'];
```

At this point the session has lost it's value.

I have considered just putting the js script in the header of the php so I can use $_GET but the js script is quite big and used another page too.

Comment: where you set $_SESSION['audit_id'] = ? I mean the first time that you created it.

Comment: It hasn't lost its value - it would appear that you have never _given it a value_.

Comment: The value for the session is set on the page that leads to the first page, I can echo the session on upload_image.php but when I echo it on upload_sucess.php the value has gone

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the value of the session variable:

```
$_SESSION['audit_id'] = $audit_id;
```

This (upload_image.php):

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['audit_id'];
$audit_id = $_SESSION['audit_id'];
```

is not setting any session variable, therefore there is no `$_SESSION['audit_id']` when you try to retrieve it.

Comment: The value is defined on an earlier page and it contains the correct value on upload_image.php but when it gets to upload_success.php the value has gone

Comment: @tatty27, post the code where it gets set...

Comment: @ jeffery, if(isset($_POST['upload_images_submit'])){  
  $_SESSION['auditID'] =$_POST['audit_id_select'];
 }  The value is fine until it gets passed to the next page

Comment: @jeffery, sussed it, where it's being declared I called it $_SESSION['auditID'] instead of 'audit_id.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your variable assignment syntax is incorrect.

`$audit_id = $_SESSION['audit_id'];` should read `$_SESSION['audit_id'] = ...some value...;` on upload_image.php

Also, the line `$_SESSION['audit_id']` is unnecessary.

Have you verified that the session is being set at all? Check out [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) for more documentation

Comment: Wait what? Are you seriously pointing the OP to w3schools? [Jesus Christ!](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Sometimes a basic question needs a basic answer.

Comment: @oomlaut, the session is being set fine, I can echo the value fine on the first page but when I echo it on the second page the session is empty.  If I just open the second page without running the js script the session has the value